# get youtube video feed in php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, youtube-api

so there is a way to get youtube video information via php/javascript. But I am not sure I should use Php or javascript.
Which method will make the page load faster?
Should I host the videos on my websites or put them on youtube and use something like JW player?

Currently, I write the code in PHP. I have a list of video ids from youtube. The php code read all of these ids, loop over them to feed information like video's titles, descriptions, etc. And display these information on the page. Thank you!

```
foreach ($vidIds as $vidId){
            $xml ="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" . $vidId;
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load($xml);
$ns = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
$title = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, "title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$desc = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, "description")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$thumbnail = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, "thumbnail")->item(2)->getAttribute("url");


<div class="preview-frame">
    <a href="player.php?vidId=<?= $vidId ?>" >
    <img class="preview-img" src="<?= $thumbnail ?>" alt="Te Cong preview image"/>
    </a>
    <div class="preview">
    <span>
    <a href="player.php?vidId=<?= $vidId ?>"><?= $title ?></a>
    </span>
    <br/>
    <?= $desc ?>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php   } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php and Javascript are fine, but if you are constantly grabbing this information from the youtube and yahoo pages you will always have a slow page.  If you can setup a cron job to cache the results and then only read from this cache at page load you should greatly speed up your page load times.  This is not a language issue it is more of a backend design issue.

Comment: thanks. I see now. Do u know the proper way to cache the results? I am guessing that I will just feed the info 1 time, save it somewhere and use these results next time. Is that right?

Comment: There are a few things you can do.

-Place it into a database of some kind, mysql ect...
-Write it to a file and then just format it in either json or something similar.
-Use a memcache server.

The first two might be the easiest to do, and the last you may or may not actually be able to do depending on your hosting of course.